# How to write the elastic search query for containing value in array if the fields having value

Tags: elasticsearch

given that there is a field in the elastic mapping, not all the entries have thie field, for example, some entries have following value

"intvalue" : [200, 201, 202]
"intvalue" : [200, 203, 204]

but some entries do not have intvalue field

I want to write a query to search the entries having values(for example, 200, 202), the query contains

{"terms":{"intvalue":[200,202],"boost":1.0}}

it will only return the results containing the value as example above.

is it possible that the query can return all the entries having the value or do not have the field, for example, I have 4 entries below

Entry A:
"intvalue" : [200, 201]
Entry B
"intvalue" : [200, 203]
Entry C
"intvalue" : []
Entry D
"intvalue" : [204, 205]

then the query {"terms":{"intvalue":[200,202],"boost":1.0}} shoudl return Entry A B, C

Comment: did you get a chance to go through my answer, looking forward to get feedback from u

Comment: its been a long time. It would be great if you can accept and upvote my answer if it helped you resolve your issue :)

Answer (score 2):

You can use [Boolean query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-bool-query.html) to combine [Exists query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-exists-query.html) and [Terms Query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-terms-query.html)

**Index Data:**

```
{ "intvalue" : [200, 201] }
{ "intvalue" : [200, 203] }
{ "intvalue" : [] }
{ "intvalue" : [204, 205] }
```

**Search Query:**

```
 {
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "should": [
        {
          "bool": {
            "must_not": {
              "exists": {
                "field": "intvalue"
              }
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "bool": {
            "must": {
              "terms": {
                "intvalue": [
                  200,
                  202
                ],
                "boost": 1.0
              }
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

**Search Result:**

```
"hits": [
      {
        "_index": "fd_cb",
        "_type": "_doc",
        "_id": "1",
        "_score": 1.0,
        "_source": {
          "intvalue": [
            200,
            201
          ]
        }
      },
      {
        "_index": "fd_cb",
        "_type": "_doc",
        "_id": "2",
        "_score": 1.0,
        "_source": {
          "intvalue": [
            200,
            203
          ]
        }
      },
      {
        "_index": "fd_cb",
        "_type": "_doc",
        "_id": "3",
        "_score": 0.0,
        "_source": {
          "intvalue": []
        }
      }
    ]
```

Comment: @Jacky Xi glad to hear that :) Can u please accept and upvote the answer as well, as this helped u to resolve your issue :)